# Prove that subsets $B$ of bounded subinterval $I$ is lebesgue measurable iff $ \lambda^*(I) = \lambda^*(B)+ \lambda^*(I\cap B^c)$

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

I'm preparing homework from Cohn's book to have less workload later. The question is in the title, and it's bit of a pity that this guy accepted an answer that was using theory not yet covered in the book, see [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1363888/subsets-b-of-bounded-subinterval-i-is-lebesgue-measurable-iff-lambdai). I'll also have you note that he probably used the first edition of the book, as the question is seperated in the second edition.

Let $I$ be a bounded subinterval of $\mathbb{R}$. Show that a subset $B$ of $I$ is Lebesgue-measurable iff $ \lambda^*(I) = \lambda^*(B)+ \lambda^*(I\cap B^c)$ where $\lambda^*(A)$ is defined as $\inf\{\sum_n(b_n-a_n) | A \subseteq \cup_n (a_n,b_n)\}$.

It's sufficiently to show that for all $A$, such that $A\subseteq \mathbb{R}$ and $\lambda^*(A)<+\infty$, that $\lambda^*(A)=\lambda^*(A\cap B)+ \lambda^*(A\cap B^c)$.

I've tried a lot of random stuff, for example:
There is a proposition which states that any bounded subinterval is $\lambda^*$-measurable. So
\begin{align*}
   \lambda^*(A)&=\lambda^*(A\cap I)+ \lambda^*(A\cap I^c) \\
      &\geq\lambda^*(A\cap B) + (\lambda^*(A\cap I^c) \\
\end{align*}
But i don't see how the given assumption can be used.

Comment: What is your Question?

Comment: thanks, changed the title :)

Comment: You are using $\lambda^*$ at one point then $\mu$ at another point.

Comment: No idea what is treated in Cohn's book. Does [this argument](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2008508/proving-caratheodory-measurability-if-and-only-if-the-measure-of-a-set-summed-wi) work in Cohn's setting?

Comment: Not to mention $u$...

Comment: @DanielFischer It doesn't. The sigma-algebra, and measure had been introduced. I'll add used definition of the Lebesgue outer-measure

Comment: What is Cohn's definition of measurability? There are various definitions, needing different proofs.

Comment: A measure is a non-zero countably additive function on a sigma-algebra such that $\mu(\emptyset)=0$.